# Frame as a container (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Python 3.4.0.

Could you help me understand what is going on here:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

f = Frame(root, borderwidth=2) #
for relief in [RAISED, SUNKEN, FLAT, RIDGE, GROOVE, SOLID]:
    Label(f, text=relief, width=10, relief = relief).pack(side=LEFT) #
    #f = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief = relief)
    #Label(f, text=relief, width=10).pack(side=LEFT)
    f.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

If I uncomment now commented lines and comment the lines that hafe '#' mark at the end, the result is the same.

First case: the present situation. It is understandable to me. Before the loop we create a frame. Then pack method places each label in the parent widget (which is f). In this case f expands and contains several labels.

Well, the second case: if I switch the comment marks.
A frame f is always new. Label is also always new. A label is always placed on a separate frame. I would suggest that 5 frames would be displayed with a different label in each frame.

Could you help me understand why the result is the same?

Comment: Well... Frames are invisible, right? So whether you use five frames or one frame, the result looks the same.

Comment: I can't understand you. I would say that a frame represents a separate window, which I cah close, drag, resize etc. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you want `Toplevel` instead of `Frame`, then. But you'll have to delete the `f.pack` line, since top level windows can't be packed.

Comment: Thank you. The question seems to be solved. If you will turn your comment into an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want five separate windows, each of which can be moved, closed, etc.

If so, you should use the `Toplevel` widget instead of `Frame`.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

for relief in [RAISED, SUNKEN, FLAT, RIDGE, GROOVE, SOLID]:
    t = Toplevel(root, borderwidth=2, relief = relief)
    Label(t, text=relief, width=10).pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```